# Searching for nearest sequence in string

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics, biopython

I need to convert contigs into their respective protein sequences given a reference genome (i.e. I need to take a substring, whose position is already known on the string, and I need to locate the nearest start and stop codons - a specific 3 letter sequence as written in the code).

This is tricky because sometimes the first position of contig will not be a multiple of three (i.e. the first three nucleotides in the contig may not perfectly match a codon).  Also, sometimes the contigs could be located in the intergenic region (i.e. between genes). The goal is to separate both coding and non-coding DNA.

This is my code so far:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna, generic_protein

start_codons = ['ATG']
stop_codons = ['TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA']

string = 'GG*TAG*CCAATT*ATG*AACGAA*TAG*GAC' #remove '*', just for visual
contigs = ['CCAA', 'TGAAC', 'GAA', 'GGAC']
positions = [5, 12, 17, 22] #position indices for each contig on string

extended_contigs = []
extended_position_contigs = []
intergenic_contigs = []
intergenic_position_contigs = []
for i in contigs:
    extended_contigs.append(#some code)
    extended_positions_contigs.append(#some code)
    intergenic_contigs.append(#some code)
    intergenic_positions_contigs.append(#some code)
```

I should get `extended_contigs = ['ATGAAC', 'ATGAACGAA']` and `extended_positions_contigs = [12, 17]`.  These are the contigs that are located within genes. In order to code them into peptides, I need to reach back in the string until I find the start codon and extend the initial contig (e.g. `TGAAC` -> `ATGAAC` and `GAA` -> `ATGAACGAA`)

I should also get `intergenic_contigs = ['CCAA', 'GGAC']` and `intergenic_positions_contigs = [5, 22]`.  When the missing code is run, the computer searches to the left of the string and finds a stop codon (e.g. `TAG`) before the start codon. Thus, the contig is located in between two genes and nothing needs to be added. These intergenic contigs are just stored in a new list.

My code continues:

```
prot_contigs = []
for i in extended_contigs:
    my_dna = Seq(i, generic_dna)
    my_prot = my_dna.translate()
    prot_contigs.append(str(my_prot))
```

Here, no new code needs to be added. After the above is run, `prot_contigs = ['MN', 'MNE']`.

The last step of code (which I need help with) will transform `prot_contigs` into `new_prot_contigs = ['MN', 'E']`.

How? If for any contig (e.g. `'TGAAC'`), the beginning or end is part of another codon (not perfect multiple of 3), the extra codon on either end will be maintained (e.g. `'MN'` stays `'MN'`).  Otherwise, if the contig (e.g. `'GAA'`) perfectly matches a codon, anything that was added onto it will be removed (e.g. `'MNE'` becomes `'E'`).

I would try to solve the 2 portions of code myself, but I am unsure on how to take a position on a string (i.e. beginning points of contig) and look along the string to find the nearest start/stop codons, so I could determine the DNA's function and accurately sequence the protein coding contigs into peptides.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I was thinking of using the 'in' operator for the first part of the code (e.g. if 'ATG' in string: ...) however, I would need to do this locally while searching to the left of a given starting position (i.e. beginning of the contigs) along the string. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that something else is in between start_codons stop_codons and contigs? (ie TGAAC -> ATGAAC and GAA -> ATGAACXXXXYYYYGAA)

Comment: Read [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Comment: This looks like a crosspost with your SE Bioinformatics question: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/searching-for-start-and-stop-codons-for-protein-sequencing-of-contigs

Answer (score 0):

This answer seemed to have been answered before

[How to find a open reading frame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114246/how-to-find-a-open-reading-frame-in-python)

But you really don't need to do this yourself (unless you really want to). There are plenty of tools that can do this easily. An example from the EMBOSS Suite.

```
getorf -find 3 genome.fna genome.orf
```

I guess it will be more tricky to do this if you are on a Windows system, but consider doing it in a virtualbox environment. Most bioinformatics is done on unix systems nowadays.