# How to execute a function once something happens until something else happens

Tags: python, loops, bioinformatics, biopython

I need to create a program that takes a file containing DNA and converts the open reading frame into protein data. I need to run the function once "ATG" occurs and until the stop codons "TAG" "TAA" or "TGA" occur.

I'm new to programming and this is what I have,

````
map = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',
    }
DNA = 'AGCCATGTAGCTAACTCAGGTTACATGGGGATGACCCCGCGACTTGGATTAGAGTCTCTTTTGGAATAAGCCTGAATGATCCGAGTAGCATCTCAG'
DNAlist = []
DNAlist1 = []
DNAlist2 = []
protein = []

for i in range(0, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist.append(DNA[i:i+3])
for i in range(1, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist1.append(DNA[i:i+3])
for i in range(2, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist2.append(DNA[i:i+3])

while True:
        if elements in DNAlist2 == 'TAG' or 'TAA' or 'TGA':
            False
        else:
            protein = ''.join([map[elements] for elements in DNAlist2])```

A sample output would be 
MLLGSFRLIPKETLIQVAGSSPCNLS
M
MGMTPRLGLESLLE
MTPRLGLESLLE
````

Comment: Please elaborate on the input and output.

Is DNAlist2 like ["ATG", "AGC", "GGA, "TGC, "TAA"] and you wish the output to be "ATGAGCGGATGC"? (In this case with the start codon, without the stop)

Does DNAlist contain extra stuff afterwards and you wish to separate?

Comment: Search for biopython translate functionality in http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec:translation

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114246/how-to-find-a-open-reading-frame-in-python

Answer (score 0):

well tried without using Biopython, went only for forward strand (no reverse) and used the translated sequence

found two ways, I am sure these are non-optimal approaches, I am waiting for somebody better here [How to find a open reading frame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114246/how-to-find-a-open-reading-frame-in-python) are fastest ways I suppose.

first one gives you ORFs even if there is no stop codon (sequence doesnt terminate so no '_' for stop codon presence :

```
mappy = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',
    }



# for i in mappy:
#     print(mappy[i])

DNA = 'AGCCATGTAGCTAACTCAGGTTACATGGGGATGACCCCGCGACTTGGATTAGAGTCTCTTTTGGAATAAGCCTGAATGATCCGAGTAGCATCTCAG'
DNAlist1 = []
DNAlist2 = []
DNAlist3 = []
# protein = []


def revProt(dna_list):
    proteinz = []
    for elements in dna_list:
        if len(elements) == 3:
            proteinz.append(mappy[elements])
    
            
    # proteinz = ''.join(proteinz)
    return ''.join([ i for i in reversed(proteinz)])

for i in range(0, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist1.append(DNA[i:i+3])
for i in range(1, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist2.append(DNA[i:i+3])
for i in range(2, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist3.append(DNA[i:i+3])
    
# for i in [DNAlist1] : #, DNAlist2, DNAlist3]:

for i in [DNAlist1, DNAlist2, DNAlist3]:
    
    protein = revProt(i)
    
    print(''.join(protein), type(''.join(protein)))
        
    seqs = []
    j = 0
    orf = []
    while True:
            if j <= len(protein)-1:
                if protein[j] == '_' :
                    if orf[0] == 'M':
                        orf.append('_')
                        seqs.append(''.join([i for i in reversed(orf)]))
                        orf = []
                    else :
                        orf = []
                        orf.append('_')
                if protein[j] not in [ '_' , 'M'] :
                    orf.append(protein[j])
                if protein[j] == 'M':
                    orf.append(protein[j])
                    seqs.append(''.join([i for i in reversed(orf)]))
                   
            else : 
                break
            j += 1
            
    
    print(seqs, '\n')
```

output:

```
QSAVRIM_A_ELLSELGLRPTMGMYGSNAVHS <class 'str'>
['MIRVASQ', 'MTPRLGLESLLE_', 'MGMTPRLGLESLLE_']   -----> here sequences 1st is at the end of DNA so no stop

LH_ES_EPKNWFLS_DLDRP_GWTVQTL_MA <class 'str'>
['M_'] 

SISSPDNLSIGFSVRIWTAPDDGHLRL_SCP <class 'str'>
[]
```

second way even more cumbersome :

```
import itertools

mappy = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',
    }

DNA = 'AGCCATGTAGCTAACTCAGGTTACATGGGGATGACCCCGCGACTTGGATTAGAGTCTCTTTTGGAATAAGCCTGAATGATCCGAGTAGCATCTCAG'


DNAlist1 = []
DNAlist2 = []
DNAlist3 = []

def Prot(dna_list):
    proteinz = []
    for elements in dna_list:
        if len(elements) == 3:
            proteinz.append(mappy[elements])
      
    # proteinz = ''.join(proteinz)
    return proteinz


def Met(protein):
    
    met = [i for i, x in enumerate(protein) if x == "M"] 
    return met
        
def Stop(protein):
    
    stop = [i for i, x in enumerate(protein) if x == "_"]   
    return stop
         
    


for i in range(0, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist1.append(DNA[i:i+3])
for i in range(1, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist2.append(DNA[i:i+3])
for i in range(2, len(DNA), 3):
    DNAlist3.append(DNA[i:i+3])
    
for i in [DNAlist1, DNAlist2, DNAlist3]:

    
    protein = Prot(i)
    
    print(''.join(protein), type(''.join(protein)))
    
    
    met = Met(protein)
    
    # print('met : ', met)
    
    stop = Stop(protein)
    
    # print('stop : ' , stop)
    
    # print('------------------')
    
    orf = [i for i in list(itertools.product(met, stop)) if i[0] < i[1]]
    
    print(orf)
    
    
    orf_p = [''.join(protein[j[0]:j[1]]) for j in orf]
    
    orf_pp = [i for i in orf_p]
    
    
    for y in orf_p:
        
        # print(y, type(y))
        if '_' in y:
            # print('ok')
            orf_pp.remove(y)
    
    print('orf_pp : ',orf_pp)
    
 
    print('______________')
```

output:

```
SHVANSGYMGMTPRLGLESLLE_A_MIRVASQ <class 'str'>
[(8, 22), (8, 24), (10, 22), (10, 24)]
orf_pp :  ['MGMTPRLGLESLLE', 'MTPRLGLESLLE']  ----->here the sequences
______________
AM_LTQVTWG_PRDLD_SLFWNKPE_SE_HL <class 'str'>
[(1, 2), (1, 10), (1, 16), (1, 25), (1, 28)]
orf_pp :  ['M']
______________
PCS_LRLHGDDPATWIRVSFGISLNDPSSIS <class 'str'>
[]
orf_pp :  []
______________
```

shorter (probably faster copied from : [How to find a open reading frame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114246/how-to-find-a-open-reading-frame-in-python)

```
import re



mappy = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',
    }



# for i in mappy:
#     print(mappy[i])

DNA = 'AGCCATGTAGCTAACTCAGGTTACATGGGGATGACCCCGCGACTTGGATTAGAGTCTCTTTTGGAATAAGCCTGAATGATCCGAGTAGCATCTCAG'


def Prot(dna_list):
    proteinz = []
    for elements in dna_list:
        if len(elements) == 3:
            proteinz.append(mappy[elements])

    return proteinz
    


pattern = re.compile(r'(?=(ATG(?:...)*?)(?=TAG|TGA|TAA))')

def revcomp(dna_seq):
    return dna_seq[::-1].translate(str.maketrans("ATGC","TACG"))

def orfs(dna):
    return set(pattern.findall(dna) + pattern.findall(revcomp(dna)))



    
for j in orfs(DNA):
        # print(j, type(j))
        DNAlistz = []
        for i in range(0, len(j), 3):
            DNAlistz.append(j[i:i+3])
        print(''.join(Prot(DNAlistz)))
    
    
print('+++++++++++++')
```

output this time with reverse strand translation too:

```
MGMTPRLGLESLLE
MTPRLGLESLLE
M
MLLGSFRLIPKETLIQVAGSSPCNLS
+++++++++++++
```